# How to call the procedure for each row in the table and write the result to a new column?

Tags: sql-server, foreach, procedure

What is the best way to add a column to a table and complete it with values returned from a procedure whose parameter is the ID contained in the table?
For example, I would like to complete such a table:

```
userID  |   column2     
21      |       132     
22      |       123     
23      |       123
```

In this way:

```
userID  |   column2     |   result  
21      |       132     |   EXEC procedure 21 result
22      |       123     |   EXEC procedure 22 result
23      |       123     |   EXEC procedure 23 result
```

Procedure returns varchar.

Keep well!

Comment: Why not build a procedure that handles the whole table, rather than having one that only accepts one (agonising) row at a time?

Comment: What is your SP code?  What is your code calling it?

Comment: Alternatively, it seems what you might *really* be after is a user defined function; if you're on SQL Server 2019 you could make use of an inline scalar function, however if you're on an older version then you'll want an inline table-value function. Avoid a multi-line function at all costs.

Comment: A procedure does not "return" a varchar - it can return an integer only. To provide anything else from the execution an output parameter must be used. In this case, you could use a cursor to loop the rows in the table and execute the procedure for each tuple. That is generally not an efficient approach but will accomplish your stated goal. As already mentioned, a set-based approach is generally preferable.